# no data available in table but data from the database is displayed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

The data table displays the the contents of the database but still shows an error message: no data available in table. 
how do i fix this, just show the data without the error message

```
<table name= "displaycase" id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped" method = "post">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Case Title</th>
      <th>Court</th>
      <th>Dockent Number</th>
      <th>Nature</th>
      <th>Actions Taken</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Due Date </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tbody class = "searchable">
    <?php
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo
        "</td><td>" . $row["CaseTitle"] .
        "</td><td>" . $row["Court"] .
        "</td><td>" . $row["docketNum"] .
        "</td><td>" . $row["nature"] .
        "</td><td>" . $row["actionsTaken"] .
        "</td> <td>" . $row["status"] .
        "</td> <td>" . $row["dueDate"] .
        "</td></tr>";
      }
    } else {
    }
    ?>
  </tbody>
```

-

```
<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#example1").DataTable({
            "paging": false,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": false,
            "language": {
                "emptyTable": "No Data"
            }
          })
    });</script>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the `method` attribute doing inside a `table` tag?!?

Comment: if you want to display data only using datatables then you are going wrong.. you just need to add <th> in the html/php file please check [link] https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove `method = "post"` from `<table>` tag.
2. Why Two `<tbody>` tag present inside `<table>`. Remove One.
3. Why `</td>` is closed when it didn't opened yet.
4. No `<tr>` opened.

**UPDATE CODE:**

```
<table name= "displaycase" id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Case Title</th>
      <th>Court</th>
      <th>Dockent Number</th>
      <th>Nature</th>
      <th>Actions Taken</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Due Date </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class = "searchable">
    <?php
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo
        "<tr>".
          "<td>" . $row["CaseTitle"] ."</td>".
          "<td>" . $row["Court"] ."</td>".
          "<td>" . $row["docketNum"] ."</td>".
          "<td>" . $row["nature"] ."</td>".
          "<td>" . $row["actionsTaken"] ."</td>".
          "<td>" . $row["status"] ."</td>".
          "<td>" . $row["dueDate"] ."</td>".
        "</tr>";
      }
    } else {

    }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[**NOTE**: [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)

Comment: +10 for rectifying all possible problem and note specially

Answer (score 0):

That's because you missed a `tr` and instead you echo `</td>` in the echo here

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo 
     "<tr><td>".$row["CaseTitle"].
     "</td><td>".$row["Court"].
     "</td><td>".$row["docketNum"].
     "</td><td>".$row["nature"].
     "</td><td>".$row["actionsTaken"].
     "</td> <td>".$row["status"].
     "</td> <td>".$row["dueDate"].
     "</td></tr>";
}
```